# python not found in the container but it is installed

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-18.04, singularity-container

I am using this command:

```
./configure --enable-2d-adaptivity
```

in order to create an executable for an open source code I would like to install in a folder outside the container.

But I get this error when it stops:

```
checking for Fortran 77 name-mangling scheme... lower case, underscore, no extra underscore
configure: Checking for Python automagic.
configure: No Python automagic.
checking for python... no
configure: error: Cannot find python in your system path`
```

This code require Python 2.7 and it is installed in `/usr/bin`.
When I use `ls -l` :

```
Singularity> ls -l /usr/bin/python*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3628976 Sep 30 09:38 /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Sep 30 09:38 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.6-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     384 Apr 11  2018 /usr/bin/python3-futurize
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     388 Apr 11  2018 /usr/bin/python3-pasteurize
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     364 Aug 22  2016 /usr/bin/python3-qr
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4526456 Oct  8 08:12 /usr/bin/python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Oct  8 08:12 /usr/bin/python3.6-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4526456 Oct  8 08:12 /usr/bin/python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      34 Oct  8 08:12 /usr/bin/python3.6m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      17 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3m-config -> python3.6m-config
```

So probably a solution could be to set `python` to point at Python 2.7?
I tried many commands but they didn't worked.
In addition when I run `which python` it is empty.
How can I fix it?

Should the folder be in the container instead of my home directory?
The folder in which I run the command `./configure --enable-2d-adaptivity` is located in the home directory of my account on a super computer. I can see it from the container.

Thank you!

Comment: You could make a symlink from `python` to `python2.7`. e.g. `ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python`

Comment: Thank you @flakes, I already tried that, but it gives this error `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/python': Read-only file system` and I don't know why.

Comment: Ah, I'm not sure how your system is configured, but perhaps try making the stnlink in some directory you can write to, and then add that directory to your PATH

Comment: Please post your Singularity definition file (or the Dockerfile, if built from that). How are you running this? `singularity exec ...`, `singularity run ...` or via an interactive session with `singularity shell`?